# How to make my css loop through without starting over again?

Tags: css

I'm trying to build s ticker ticket that loops its content and when it's finishing its content loop over it again, but it's starting from 0, it looks really awkward because it clears itself and ends up running the content from the beginning instead of starting up the content like it would happen on a loop

```css
/* OUTER CONTAINER */

.tcontainer {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Hide scroll bar */
}


/* MIDDLE CONTAINER */

.ticker-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 100%;
  /* Push contents to right side of screen */
  background-color: #eee;
}


/* INNER CONTAINER */

@keyframes ticker {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}

.ticker-move {
  /* Basically move items from right side of screen to left in infinite loop */
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 100%;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-name: ticker;
  animation-duration: 0s;
}

.ticker-move:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  /* Pause scroll on mouse hover */
}


/* ITEMS */

.ticker-item {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Lay items in a horizontal line */
  padding: 0 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="tcontainer">
  <div class="ticker-wrap">
    <div class="ticker-move">
      <div class="ticker-item"><a href="#">USD/MXN 21.07 -1.02 (-0.73)</a></div>
      <div class="ticker-item"><a href="#">Oro 21.07 -1.02 (-0.73)</a></div>
      <div class="ticker-item"><a href="#">Plata 21.07 -1.02 (-0.73)</a></div>
      <div class="ticker-item"><a href="#">WTI Oil 21.07 -1.02 (-0.73)</a></div>
      <div class="ticker-item"><a href="#">Nasdaq 100 21.07 -1.02 (-0.73)</a></div>
      <div class="ticker-item"><a href="#">S&P 500 21.07 -1.02 (-0.73)</a></div>
      <div class="ticker-item"><a href="#">EUR/USD 1.18 -1.02 (-0.73)</a></div>
      <div class="ticker-item"><a href="#">BTC/USD 17152.02 -1.02 (-0.73)</a></div>
      <div class="ticker-item"><a href="#">Amazon 3171.07 -1.02 (-0.73)</a></div>
      <div class="ticker-item"><a href="#">Apple 119.07 -1.02 (-0.73)</a></div>
      <div class="ticker-item"><a href="#">Visa 210.07 -1.02 (-0.73)</a></div>
      <div class="ticker-item"><a href="#">Mastercard 331.07 -1.02 (-0.73)</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you also have some other issues here. When I copy your code to codepen it is displayed in a really weird way.

Comment: Try this link https://codepen.io/lewismcarey/pen/GJZVoG

Comment: It is working. What do you expect it to do? It is already looping. Please clarify.

Comment: Is it the gap before it starts again that is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that when the ticket ends, it doesnt scroll naturally or organically to its begining, it looks like it cuts the whole animation and does not even finish to send the last element of that list to the end of the ticket-band, it just abruptally cuts itself at half way and starts all over again

Comment: The codepen works perfectly fine for me, I do not see where it breaks halfway through the animation. Are there steps I need to follow to reproduce the issue? What browser and version are you using?